# Jicama moldy on the outside but white inside, is this safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables, mold

My jicama has mold on the outside.
If I cut off the outside part, the inside part looks okay.

Can I still eat it?

Answer (score 1):

Rinse it off after skinning it and you will be fine. mold won't be able to penetrate jicama very far.